# Is it bad to continuously power off a desktop monitor by disconnecting it from the power socket instead of using the power button?

Tags: display, poweroff, powerstrip

I have my desktop computer in such a set up in that the computer is directly connected to the wall socket, but the display and other devices (a lamp, phone chargers, USB hubs, etc.) are connected to a power strip (multi-socket adaptor), which I power off when I want to shut everything down. I also do this to avoid excess power consumption of chargers and devices in stand-by mode when I am not using my computer.

Is this harmful for electronic devices, particularly for a desktop monitor? I consider that in practice this is as if I was pulling the power cable out of the wall socket, although the power strip I use has a button to turn it off, so I wonder as well if this detail milds the potential harmfulness of the method I am using.

Comment: I'd be less worried about the monitor, and more worried about other devices (e.g. printer) you may have plugged in to this power strip.

Comment: Also, I believe this is a good question, but it really shouldn't be requesting an opinion, as Super User frowns on 'primarily opinion based' questions. Rather the question should be asking for what kind of damage this can cause, and whether it is a cause for concern, or minor enough to be considered negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I agree, formulating a question is better than requesting an opinion. 
BTW, I have no devices with sensible electronics nor moving parts connected to this power strip, just a couple of lamps, a sub-woofer and some phone chargers.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the risk of data loss from unchanged settings, turning off devices this way is not going to be very problematic, and, in fact this is exactly how monitors were controlled 20 years  ago  (but thats not really relevant as tech has changed).

That said turning ON a device is stressful for it, due to inrush current - ie the transition from nothing to being powered up draws more current then leaving a device on. This causes stress to components and shortens it's life. Depending on how long you expect the device to last and how well it was built, this might be relevant.

Comment: So leaving the monitor in stand-by my be worst for the environment (and my electric bill) but may benefit it's lifetime? Does this have something to do with any particular component of an electronic device, such as capacitors?

Comment: @madfury I'm not at all sure that leaving it on standby is significantly less stressful then fully off as most components will still be off. Yes, caps (and diodes/rectifiers) are big ones, but really any electronic component having significant  current suddenly rush through it will be stressed.

Answer (score 0):

There was a report in german computer magazine CT 22/2018  about an OLED LG TV.
This TV was always powered off and got defective pixels after 18 months of use.
A replacement was rejected by the manufacturer. He stated that the TV needs to refresh its pixels regulary in standby mode.
The magazine recommends not to switch off OLED panels completely.

https://www.heise.de/ct/ausgabe/2018-22-LG-verweigert-Garantie-bei-OLED-TV-4185338.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/OLED/comments/8v4sii/pixel_refresh_how_does_it_work/

Comment: That claim is nonsense. Particularly the part about the TV doing this while it's in standby.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my monitor is LCD. I was not able to read that report, but I get the idea that the stand-by mode is mandatory in some displays, and also got me thinking that maybe it causes less tear and wear than powering off the device.